# How can I get the array index of a button I clicked out of multiple buttons

Tags: php, forms, form-control

I have a form for a shopping cart that lists the details of each stored item by iteration using `$_SESSION`. This form consists of same multiple form controls including `<button>` elements for cancellation.

The problem I'm faced with is I cannot get PHP to identify which cancellation `<button>` was clicked, so I'm unable to specify the item to delete from the form.

The code of the form controls goes:

```
......

if(isset($_SESSION[$i]['stocks']) && $_SESSION[$i]['stocks'] !== ''):
echo '<dl><dt>Quantity</dt><dd><input name="stock[]" type="text" value="'.$_SESSION[$i]['stocks'].'"></dd></dl>';
endif;
echo '<button name="cancel[]">Cancel</button>';
......
```

The cancel button has an `name` attribute in array format and also running `var_dump` returns all of the content of `$_SESSION[]`.

Please help me find any ways to identify which cancel button was clicked.

Thanks for reading this.

Comment: With a javascript click event call, you can use Ajax to delete the item from `$_SESSION`.

Comment: I have no knowledge of Ajax. Are there any other ways you can get the array index of the clicked cancel button?

Comment: If you don't want to use Ajax/Javascript, you can make each button as `<input name="cancel" value="itemId1" type="submit"  />` and use the name and value attribute to get the item and delete it from the session like so: `if (isset($_POST['cancel'])) {//delete}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every HTML button element can have a value attribute. Just fill it with the identifier you need to identify your cancel button.

```
<button name="cancel" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($i) ?>" type="submit">
    Cancel
</button>
```

When submitting the form you can access the identifier with `$_POST['cancel']` in your php script.

The button and its value is only submitted if the button was used to submit the form. You have to use the type attribute to submit the form.

When using AJAX (for god 's sake don 't use jQuery!) you don 't have to use the type attribute when setting an event listener on the button. Just read out the value and use it as query argument for your request.

```
<button name="cancel" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($i) ?>">
    Cancel
</button>
<script>
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button[name="cancel"]');
buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let value = event.currentTarget.value;
        let response = await fetch('cancel.php?item=' + value);
        ...
    });
});
</script>
```

The example sets an event listener that listens on a click event and fires an async request to `cancel.php` with the query argument, e.g. `ìtem=1`. The value is determined dynamically from the value attribute of the button with each click and is available to you in the PHP script with `$_GET['item']`.

The example shown is not good because it sets an event listener for each button. This can lead to performance problems of the HTML page depending on the number of buttons. It would be better if a single event listener is set on the parent form element, which is then used to determine the respective buttons. The example shown is only intended as an illustration.

For details using the JavaScript fetch API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: You said, `(for god 's sake don 't use jQuery!)`. Why not to use jQuery?

Comment: @PracticalOpportunist Because it 's an dependency you don 't need. jQuery is just a wrapper which wraps native JavaScript functionality that is slower than using exactly the same JavaScript functionality directly. Dependencies on this level are bad. The more dependencies you have, the more you have to manage. It raises security risks when not updating and running into an outdated version. Debugging can be difficult.

Comment: I also agreed with the view of @Marcel concerning dependencies. I'd like to avoid using AJAX or jQuery and keep it simple as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I initially struggled to output the iteration count variable passed to the value of the submit type <button> because of multiple cancel buttons, but in the end I managed to output it using a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to identify each row with some unique ID/value. Below shown example may help you.

What I have done here is, I have just added a new custom attribute to `button` tag called `data-target`. Along with this, I have added a custom class `actionBtn` to identify all such buttons in JS.

```
......

if(isset($_SESSION[$i]['stocks']) && $_SESSION[$i]['stocks'] !== ''):
echo '<dl><dt>Quantity</dt><dd><input name="stock[]" type="text" value="'.$_SESSION[$i]['stocks'].'"></dd></dl>';
endif;

// you can change the array element with unique ID or unique value for each row instead of `$_SESSION[$i]['stocks']`
echo '<button class="actionBtn" name="cancel[]" data-target="'.$_SESSION[$i]['stocks'].'">Cancel</button>';
......
```

After this, I have created a JS event which triggers a JS function when these buttons clicked. I am assuming you are using jQuery in your project.

```
<script>
$(function(){
     $('.actionBtn').on('click',function(event){
          // cancel all default actions when button clicked.
          event.preventDefault();
         
          // to make you understand, we are creating a variable which stores the values that needs to be removed from `$_SESSION`
          var target_to_remove = $(this).attr('data-target');

          // Now I am sending the value to server via AJAX call.
          $.post('<some_destination_url>.php',{target : target_to_remove},function(response){
             /* ... Do necessary action here after you receive response from server ... */
             if($.trim(response) == 'success')
             {
                 alert('success');
             } else {
                 alert('failed');
             }
          });
     });
});
</script>
```

Now as the JS part is done, We have to capture the `$_POST` data in PHP script.

**File:** <some_destination_url>.php

```
  if(isset($_POST['target']))
  {
      for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION);$i++)
      {
          if($_SESSION[$i]['stocks'] == $_POST['target'])
          {
               /* if you want to remove whole parent array then use below */
               //unset($_SESSION[$i]);

               /* if you want to remove 3rd level array element only, then use below */
               //unset($_SESSION[$i]['stocks']);

               // finally echo something back to JS so that it knows task was successfull or not.
               echo 'success';
          }

      }
      // echo failure if no elements found.
      echo 'item not found';
  }
  else 
  {
     // echo something if `$_POST` is not set.
     echo 'Invalid attempt to remove array element.';
  }
```

Comment: The use of the data attribute may indeed prove useful, thanks!